# jmeter, regular expression extractor with parallel controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

Sorry for my poor English, and thank you in advance.

I'm trying to make a thread group that makes `jmeter` logged in our system.
to accomplish this, I need to `POST` data which contains `ID, password, and token.`

The token generated every time when the page has opened and hold in hidden value.
So, the usual solution which is like `GET` response, do the regular expression extractor, and make the value variable and `POST` it later request doesn't work for me.
since the token become different from when `jmeter GET token` and `POST` it.

Then, I found a parallel controller and this might be a solution for me.
but I can't find a way to do it.
also, there are no references in my mother language(Japanese).
I want `POST` token to certain login action so I need to do regular expression extractor with parallel controller.
then `POST` the token with `ID and password` at same time.

I want to know the way of the above or if it's impossible, is there any alternative solution that might work for me.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: perhaps install selenium plugin and try to hold the cookie for the rest of the test?

Comment: Hi, Just to make it clear, can you let me know if I have understood your scenario correctly? 
1. We send a GET request we will get a response with token
2. We need to get token and send a POST with username, Id, Password. 
What is not clear to me is when is the token is going to get changed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The token got generated every time we send request, and got response from the apprication, so the token will be change when 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about language at all :)
I will add a solution according to how I understand your problem.

As I understood, your scenario is,

- We Request a page
- We will get a response with token
- We fetch the token and send the next request with the token
- We will get a response with a different token
- Need to fetch the new token and send another request

In this case, I think you are trying to use the first token in all the requests. Without doing that what if you fetch the token per each request?

The problem with the parallel controller is if you want to fetch the token from a previous request. It might not work.

Please correct me if I haven't understood the question correctly

Comment: Thanks!

What I need to do to is send the values which contain ID, password, and the token.
The token got generated every time I send a request.(It will be different every time we open the login form.)

So, fetch the token from the first request and use it later request don't work, since the required token for the later request will be changed from we open the login form for the first time.

I'm thinking use selenium plugin, control browser and keep that information for the rest of the test scenario might works for me.
But I don't know how to make it happen.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For Example, let's say it's something like a csrf token. Whenever we send a request GET or POST are we not getting the changed token in every response?

Comment: If you can you tell me the exact scenario you want to do. Like, login to a system, go to the profile page, fill a form ... like that. And Have you added the cookie manager and the cache manager? From your explanation what I feel is this is like a normal login system with a different token for each user. Try to add the Cache Manager and Cookie Manager from config Elements and try again.

Comment: Thanks!
I want to make scenario of login!
I added Cookie Manager but not with Cache Manager, so I'll challenge to use Cache Manager or combine both!
And yes, that is like csrf token, one time token or that kind of token which is valid for only one time.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Cool, so in this case, extracting the token from each response and attaching it with the next request should work. Since threads do not share the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Controller is not something you should be using, it's for simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests as [JMeter cannot execute JavaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/) like browser does and hence cannot run multiple HTTP request samplers in parallel with one virtual user.

Your test plan structure should be much simpler, to wit:

- HTTP Request sampler (to get login page)

  - a Post-Processor (most probably you're looking for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/)) to get the values from hidden fields
- HTTP Request sampler (to perform login)

See [Variabilize and Correlate the script](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) chapter for more details on the concept